# linear equation with floating constants

Tags: euclidean-algorithm

I am to know the solution of equations like:

```
5.5*x + 1.33*y = 125(124.99 will also do), in which x and y are positive integers..
```

I tried extended Euclidean algorithm, but it does't seem to work.. anyone..

Comment: Is it $125$ or $124.99$? And is it $1.33$ or $\frac43$? And is it exactly $5.5$? These details are _important_ when looking for integer solutions.

Comment: Though it is 125, but approximation upto 124.99 will do.. it is 1.33 only.. but my question is not just about this particular equation, but similar equations